# Karma Setup with Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am working to setup karma with an Angular 2 web application. However, I am stuck on trying to get karma to load my application files and my .spec files. I have been working on this for days, and still no luck.

I took the code from the angular quick start application on github, and I modified it to accommodate my current setup.

So far I have only been able to get karma to report 404s. I am not sure where to go from here or what questions I could ask because I have tried everything that I can think of. Also there is very little information on how to properly configure Karma with Angular 2 and System js, so any help or good tutorials will be greatly appreciated.

The current setup of my application

```
root:
  systemjs.config.js
  app -> contains my ts files and transpiled files
  node_modules
  test
    |_ karma.conf.js
    |_ karma-test-shim.js
    |_ protractor.config.js
    |_ unit
          |_ all spec files
    |_ e2e
          |_ all protractor test files
```

and here is my current karma configuration files

Karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  var app = './app/'; // app source TS files
  var testBase = 'target/build/unit/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrc = 'test/unit/'; // test source TS files
  var node_modules = 'node_modules/';

  config.set({
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-ie-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher')
    ],
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      node_modules + 'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      node_modules + 'core-js/client/shim.js',
      node_modules + 'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      node_modules + 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      node_modules + 'requirejs/requirejs.js',

      // RxJs
      {pattern: node_modules + 'rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: node_modules + 'rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      // Paths loaded via module imports: Angular itself
      {pattern: node_modules + '@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: node_modules + '@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'test/karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application files
      {pattern: app + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

      //transpiled spec files
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.spec.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: app + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: app + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: app + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: app + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testSrc + '**/*.spec.ts', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": '/base/app/'
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    colors: true,
  });
}
```

karma-test-shim,js

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.Spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: '/base',

  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': '../node_modules/:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('../systemjs.config.js')
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

Systemjs.config.js

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'primeng':                    'node_modules/primeng',
    'ic-components':              'node_modules/ic-components'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'primeng':                    { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ic-components':              { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

The error that I am getting

```
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js
[INFO]  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js
[INFO]  Error loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js', '; Zone:', '<root>', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error{originalErr: Error{}}, '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js
[INFO]  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js
[INFO]  Error loading http://localhost:9090/systemjs.config.js'
[INFO] 
[INFO] Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR: Error{rejection: Error{originalErr: Error{}}, promise: ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: Error{originalErr: ...}}, zone: Zone{_properties: Object{}, _parent: null, _name: '<root>', _zoneDelegate: ZoneDelegate{_taskCounts: ..., zone: ..., _parentDelegate: ..., _forkZS: ..., _forkDlgt: ..., _interceptZS: ..., _interceptDlgt: ..., _invokeZS: ..., _invokeDlgt: ..., _handleErrorZS: ..., _handleErrorDlgt: ..., _scheduleTaskZS: ..., _scheduleTaskDlgt: ..., _invokeTaskZS: ..., _invokeTaskDlgt: ..., _cancelTaskZS: ..., _cancelTaskDlgt: ..., _hasTaskZS: ..., _hasTaskDlgt: ...}}, task: ZoneTask{runCount: 1, type: 'microTask', zone: Zone{_properties: ..., _parent: ..., _name: ..., _zoneDelegate: ...}, source: 'Promise.then', data: undefined, scheduleFn: undefined, cancelFn: null, callback: function () { ... }, invoke: function () { ... }}}
[INFO] 
[INFO] [33m03 11 2016 14:14:45.699:WARN [Firefox 49.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
[INFO] Firefox 49.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO]   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [36m03 11 2016 14:14:45.738:DEBUG [launcher]: [39mProcess Firefox exited with code 0
[INFO] [33m03 11 2016 14:14:45.885:WARN [Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
[INFO] Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO]   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
```

I have tried playing around the with the baseUrl, basePath, and changing the included to true under the karma files array. However, all of the different modifications have resulted in different cryptic errors.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think in your karma-test-shim.js you don't want all those paths beginning with `../`, for example `System.import('../systemjs.config.js')` should be `System.import('systemjs.config.js')`. The two dots tell the browser to go one level up from the base URL which effectively erases 'base' from the URL. The error you're seeing shows that the browser doesn't have 'base' in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is exactly what it was. After fixing a few issues, I was able to get it to run.